# Android SQLite No such table exists

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an application which uses 2 tables in the same database. I create and prefill these tables in an helper class as shown below.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "CREATE  TABLE [weekmenu] ([weekmenuID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, [receptenLijst] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL )";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    sql = "INSERT INTO weekmenu (receptenLijst) values('0')"; db.execSQL(sql);


    sql = "CREATE  TABLE [recepten] ([receptID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, [receptNaam] TEXT NOT NULL  UNIQUE, [receptURL] TEXT )";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    sql = "INSERT INTO recepten (receptNaam, receptURL) values('Macaroni met spek en broccoli', 'http://www.kooknet.be/recepten/hoofdgerecht/macaroni-met-spek-en-broccoli')"; db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "INSERT INTO recepten (receptNaam, receptURL) values('Broccolipuree met spekblokjes en fishsticks', 'http://www.kooknet.be/recepten/hoofdgerecht/broccolipuree-met-spekblokjes-en-fishsticks')"; db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "INSERT INTO recepten (receptNaam, receptURL) values('Hoeveomelet', 'http://www.kooknet.be/recepten/hoofdgerecht/hoeveomelet')"; db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "INSERT INTO recepten (receptNaam, receptURL) values('Gevulde courgettes', 'http://www.kooknet.be/recepten/hoofdgerecht/gevulde-courgettes')"; db.execSQL(sql);   

}
```

In another activity I want to make sure that users can update the table weekmenu when they press a button. Each time when the user hits the button the same record in weekmenu should be overwritten (by updating the table)

```
        btnWeekmenuOpslaan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // Database aanroepen
        SQLiteDatabase db = oData.getReadableDatabase();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            String receptenLijst =
                    txtMaandagReceptID.getText().toString() + "-" +
                    txtDinsdagReceptID.getText().toString() + "-" +
                    txtWoensdagReceptID.getText().toString() + "-" +
                    txtDonderdagReceptID.getText().toString() + "-" +
                    txtVrijdagReceptID.getText().toString() + "-" +
                    txtZaterdagReceptID.getText().toString() + "-" +
                    txtZondagReceptID.getText().toString();

            // database updaten
            values.put("receptenLijst", receptenLijst);         
            db.update("weekmenu", values, "weekmenuID=?",new String[] {Long.toString(1)});
            db.close();
            oData.close();              
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately the activity stops and in debugging mode I get the message that the "weekmenu: no such table exists".

Can anyone help me please? I have been reading a lot of posts on Stackoverflow, but none of them could help me.

Thanks!

Comment: why the [] around the table and column names ?

Comment: @njzk2 Not necessary in this case ([explanation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)) and not standard SQL.

Comment: exactly `This is not standard SQL`. double quotes should be used.

Comment: It does not result in any error when reading the recepten table though. I only get an error when writing to the weekmenu table.

Answer (score 0):

Your culprit is here:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = oData.getReadableDatabase();
```

You need a writable database. Not a readable one.

Change it to:

```
QLiteDatabase db = oData.getWritableDatabase();
```